# Class name must be a valid object or a string Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I want to save a new record, but Laravel gives me this error **Class name must be could object or a string.** my code;

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $question = new Question;
    $question->question = $request->question;
    $question->question_type_id = $request->question_type;
    $question->user_id = $request->Auth::id();
    $question->save();
}
```

> **Note:** My PHP version is latest **.i.e.,** 7.1.9

Comment: `$request->Auth::id();` is not correct. Use `$question->user_id = Auth::id();` instead.

Comment: $request->Auth::id(); This doesn't look valid.

Comment: @aynber oh I have copied the above code two times I didn't see this one thanks for help answer it I will accept, thanks again man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, thanks to **aynber** for sorting out my issue. I have changed

```
$question->user_id = $request->Auth::id();
```

to

```
$question->user_id = Auth::id();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you created an input field that has a name of the user’s id and you are trying to access it with:

```
$request->Auth::id()
```

Which for a user with a user id of one, I assume you are asking to pass request item `$request->1`.

This won’t work as `Auth::id()` is being passed as a literal. Accessing the request object it’s complaining saying "hey, I can’t accept a class as a variable name, please stop!"

If this is in fact what you are trying to do, and `Auth::id()` works (I never used that, I typically use `Auth::user()->id`),  then you would have to pass the function within parentheses like this:

```
$request->(Auth::id())
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for dynamic object key is:

```
$question->user_id = $request->{Auth::id()};
```

or if you just want the auth ID, then it is:

```
$question->user_id = Auth::id();
```